# FileZilla 3.38.1 file associations on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: 18.04, gedit, file-association

I am trying to set up file associations in FileZilla 3.38.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

If I double-click on eg. `test.php` in Files it will open in gedit.

So in `FileZilla > edit > settings > Filetype` Associations I tick the "Inherit system's filetype associations" (there is nothing else defined in there) and right click > Open a LOCAL `test.php` it asks me if I want to open it with "Text Editor", "LibreOffice Writer" or "Atom" and opening with those works. I would expect it to just open with the default editor, gedit.

If I right-click > View/Edit on a remote `test.php` I get an error-
"An assertion failed. ./src/common/filefn.cpp(1610): assert "!szFile.empty()" failed in wxFindFileInPath(): empty file name in wxFindFileInPath" and whichever button I choose, "Stop" or "Continue" FileZilla crashes. I would expect FileZilla to download a temp local copy of the file and open it in gedit.

Also if I right-click > Edit on a LOCAL `test.php` I get the same error/crash.

So, I try to set up gedit as the default editor in FileZilla Filetype Associations.

First, I type into the Terminal `which gedit` and the response is: `/usr/bin/gedit`

If I type `/usr/bin/gedit` in the terminal gedit starts.

So in filezilla I try -
php "/usr/bin/gedit" (also tried without quotes)

FileZilla tells me "Associated Program not found".

In local file window in FileZilla, if I go to /usr/bin I cannot see a gedit file or folder, yet I can see it in Files or via "ls" in terminal.

Why can't Filezilla see gedit?

Comment: Have you tried associating file types with applications using your file manager instead of the application? Browse to a PHP file, right-click and look for the "open with" tab, then select a text editor. Does this help, or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Opening files in "File Manager" works fine. I want to open remote files in FileZilla so I can view or edit them. Usually, it would download a local copy and then edit it in the default editor, and give me the option to upload it again if I changed it, but it doesn't.

Comment: See my Q&A at https://askubuntu.com/q/1473992/1201916

Comment: I had the same problem on Ubuntu 23.04 using Filezilla 3.63.0. Short answer is you probably just need to drop /usr and just use /bin/gedit (See my Q&A at https://askubuntu.com/q/1473992/1201916)

Answer (score 1):

you've this probleme because you have install a snap **Filezila(UNOFFICIAL)** from ubuntu app store.
This work for me.
purge the current filezilla and do **reinstall** like this in terminal command

> **sudo apt-get install filezilla**

Comment: I had the same problem with the Flatpak version and installing from apt really fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You was almost right in your setup, you just had to add the extension.

in your example you had /usr/bin/gedit

All you needed was `php /usr/bin/gedit`

Hopefully this will work for you.

Comment: That's what I tried. It seems that FileZilla cannot see gedit. I've been using FileZilla on Ubuntu and Linux for years, never had problems like this before.