# Need location of gedit in Ubuntu 23.04 to add to Filezilla 3.63.0 filetype associations

Tags: gedit, 23.04, filezilla

I am trying to locate the gedit app in my newly installed Ubuntu 23.04.

In filezilla I am adding **Filetype associations** under **File editing** for various text file types such as txt, png, html and wish to use gedit.

If I put `txt /usr/bin/gedit %f` for example filezilla throws an error stating it cannot find the associated program, yet that is the correct location.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I followed a tip and tried modifying **Use custom editor** under **Default editor** under **Settings > File editing** and  chose to browse for gedit:

I had the correct location: `/usr/bin/gedit`

I tried using that location and filezilla still gave me grief until I removed the `%f` and then it worked fine.